# How to transform an XML adding a child node using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML document as an input (**InputXML**) to a Java program that applies a XSL (**TransformationXSL**) to convert to output XML (**OutputXML**).

I want to add an extra node as part of the transformation of the input XML. Is there a better way than what is being shown in the (**TranformationXSL**), as this just tries to match the element and copy what's required??? Any other efficient way / suggestion is much appreciated.

**InputXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tuple>
    <old>
        <Customers>
            <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
            <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
            <EmployeeID>8</EmployeeID>
            <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00.0</OrderDate>
            <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
            <CompanyName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</CompanyName>
        </Customers>
    </old>
</tuple>
```

**OutputXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tuple>
    <old>
        <Customers>
            <Orders>
                <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
                <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
                <EmployeeID>8</EmployeeID>
                <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00.0</OrderDate>
            </Orders>
            <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
            <CompanyName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</CompanyName>                
        </Customers>
    </old>
</tuple>
```

This is the **TransformationXSL** that I was talking about. Can this be modified to efficiently transform the input XML to give the desired output XML???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customers">
        <Customers>
            <Orders>
                <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
                <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
                <EmployeeID>8</EmployeeID>
                <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00.0</OrderDate>
            </Orders>
            <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
            <CompanyName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</CompanyName>
        </Customers>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What's the logic behind grouping few elements inside `Orders` and few not?

Comment: Logical differentiator is just that the columns from Orders table (NORTHWIND database, MS SQL Server) to be put under Orders tag, rest of the elements are columns from Customers table.

Comment: Your XSLT makes no sense to me: why are you hard-coding the values? -- As for the question: will there always be only one record, containing one order and one customer?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to come up with an XSL as like what I shared, but to achieve the required output I didn't find a better solution. Thanks to @Alexey, I have one! To answer your questions, yes, always one order and a customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you show can be obtained easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Customers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Orders>
            <xsl:copy-of select="OrderID | CustomerID[1] | EmployeeID | OrderDate"/>
        </Orders>
        <xsl:copy-of select="CustomerID[1] | CompanyName"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If double tag `CustomerID` in the **InputXML** is an error, then check my solution below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml"
                version="1.0"
                encoding="utf-8"
                indent="yes"
                standalone="yes"
                omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderID">
        <xsl:element name="Orders">
            <xsl:element name="OrderID">
                <xsl:value-of select="../OrderID/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="CustomerID">
                <xsl:value-of select="../CustomerID/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="EmployeeID">
                <xsl:value-of select="../EmployeeID/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="OrderDate">
                <xsl:value-of select="../OrderDate/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EmployeeID"/>
    <xsl:template match="OrderDate"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this. What if, if the CustomerID is required under the `Customers` tag as well as under the `Orders` tag? Can something be done to have only one element under `Customers`? (it is repeating twice now!)